# Not getting reply to questions as earlier

Tags: support, questions

I'm in a doubt as  I'm not getting replies to  my questions. 
I would request the moderators to cross check that everything 
is fine at your end & there is no issue like blockage of sorts on my
questions.

Comment: What questions? The last question you asked that I can see was asked today and has already received an answer. Does that put your mind at ease?

Comment: Retagging this as [support] not [bug] because there is no evidence in the question that you are seeing incorrect software behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no shadowban-like state in which you can post questions but they aren't displayed to other users. It is possible to be blocked from posting questions entirely, but you would get an error message when you tried. If you're able to post questions, other users can see them